# Synchronize Lint Config in Android Studio with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, configuration, lint

I want to run the Android Lint checks on my Android projects. Is it possible to use a single configuration file for both the Android Studio Code Inspection and the inspection executed via the Gradle task? I don't want to maintain two different configs for the IDE and Gradle.

I am thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an all-encompassing solution for this.

If you create a lint.xml file, it will override the Inspection settings in Android Studio, and will be used for highlighting in the IDE, Commit-time "Perform code analysis" checks, and command line lint checking, but will NOT impact the "Inspect Code" functionality.

However, if you set up your Inspection settings, they will be used for highlighting in the IDE, Commit-time "Perform code analysis" checks, and "Inspect Code", but will NOT work with command line lint checking.

I thought about writing a script to convert between the two formats so I could write the rules once and keep them synchronized, but that seems fragile and not worth the effort.  I believe we're just going to stick with using lint.xml because it will work better with Jenkins, and not worry about "Inspect Code".

While researching this, I also discovered that it's possible to create a GitHub repo containing your Android Studio settings (including Inspections) and have them automatically synchronized within a team of developers.  More information on that is available here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/settings-repository.html

If you think of something better, I would be interested in hearing what you come up with.

Comment: Thanks. 'Highlighting in the IDE' and 'command line lint checking' are enough for me.